# Are there any downsides to reference the same .war file from many Jetty server instances?

Tags: java, webserver, legacy, jetty-9

I have a system with many Jetty servers running in parallel (each one on a different port), but they all use the same .war file (copied into each of the folders and referenced in their respective context.xml file).
To make the update process easier, instead of swapping each .war file inside each of the jetty folders, I want to create a single .war file placed somewhere else, and every context.xml file will reference it (for example, C:\war\app.war).
Will this cause any problems with information being leaked from an app to another?
I know that jetty will extract the contents of the .war file to a work folder inside its respective folder structure and read it from there, but I don't know if this is enough to prevent any leaking of session info from the instances?

I'm running jetty 9.3 (yes, I know), and any other suggestions of changes to this structure would also be appreciated, although the one i'm asking about would be a nice and easy change that would save me a lot of time.

I know I CAN reference the same .war file, but i'm unsure about the consequences of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Will this cause any problems with information being leaked from an app to another?

No.

> I know that jetty will extract the contents of the .war file to a work folder inside its respective folder structure and read it from there, but I don't know if this is enough to prevent any leaking of session info from the instances?

I can't think of any (plausible) way that information *could* go:

- from a running webapp in one Jetty instance
- to the web container's exploded folder (read only)
- to the WAR file (read only)
- to an exploded folder (read only) in a different Jetty instance
- to the webapp running in the 2nd Jenny instance.

Session information *could* potentially leak between Jetty instances if they use the same session tokens and the same database to hold persistent session information.  But that has nothing to do with sharing WAR files.

I can't think of any downsides of sharing WAR files.

Comment: Thank you, I think my question had its origin on not knowing about the read-only quality of those folders and files. This makes me more confident about trying to re-manage the system structure.